# How can I discover new music based on what I have downloaded as mp3

Tags: playlists

I tried itunes genius but for each track it says it can't do it. Ideally I need something that will scan my entire library and give me albums, songs and artist I might like

Comment: What do you mean, for each track, it says it can't do it...? From what I found, "**Genius Playlists: Choose a song, and iTunes creates a playlist of songs that sound great together**."

Answer (score 1):

Use an scrobbler like [Last.fm](https://www.last.fm). It will detect the songs you listen to using the ID3 tags embedded in the files and will suggest new music based on what you have been listening to.

Last.fm was a huge thing before the age of Spotify and many hardcore music fans still use it to keep track of what they listen to. Spotify has built-in support for Last.fm but almost every other source (YouTube, Bandcamp, SoundCloud, you name it) can be scrobbled using the official client or some sort of plugin. As it is almost source agnostic, it can act as a central repository for all the music you consume.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Spotify it's much better and absolutely free and It actually makes **Playlist Every SINGLE DAY by  analysing your interest** And if it's not available in your country you can actually use it by using VPN.

Comment: I don't think Spotify will scan your personal music library and end up with suggestions...